# I am dissecting a SQL statement and cannot find out what the "parse_activity" statement does

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I am dissecting a SQL statement and cannot find out what the "parse_activity" statement does. I can find nothing with the following syntax:

```
WITH PARSE_ACTIVITY AS (
    SELECT C.SOURCE_ID SUBMISSION_ID, C.NEED_BY_DT, C.PENDING_DT, C.ASSIGNED_DT,
           A.CREATE_HID, A.WORKFLOW_ACTIVITY_ID, A.WORKFLOW_COMMENT_ID, A.BUS_DIVISION_CD *.... etc....*
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird? The construct itself is called a common table expression and is part of the SQL standard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expression#Common_table_expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking at is known as a Common Table Expression (CTE).

For use of CTEs in Oracle, see http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/with.html

For use of CTEs in Microsoft SQL Server, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: sorry... Oracle 11c, we use Toad for most DB access.  I had never seen "with_ " as part of a query. I am quite the noob, i will admit.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer accordingly.  Hope you find it useful.